# BigQuery - select from nested table to another table

Tags: google-bigquery, bigdata

I loaded nested json file to a table and got nested table.
Now i want to filter the table data by where clause and insert it to another table.

so i will do destination table  - new table
and source table  = select * from old_nested_table where status=1

The problem is that the select * is flatten the old nested table while i want to keep it nested.

How can i query nested table in order to get nested results?

Answer (score 2):

You should

> check on "Allow Large Results"

and

> check off "Flatten Results"

as below

[image]

These settings allow you to save result preserving schema of original table

Comment: thanks, but it's not helping me when i want to do union and get nested records.

Comment: didnt see any union things in your original question